# Time-Series Analysis versus ODE parameter estimation -- why does one use first differences (stationarity) and the other does not?

Tags: time-series, fitting, differences, differential-equations

This is kinda a tricky question, because it crosses disciplines. But I looking at the difference between time-series analysis in statistics, versus fitting parameters to ordinary differential equations. Now technically, both types of models are time series models. An ordinary differential equation (ODE) in the most common cases, plots the evolution of a state vector or variable over time.

Now, say I have a set of time series data, such as economic growth or someone's heart rate measurements over time, it does not matter. If I was going to use a classical time series method such as AR, or ARIMA, etc., then I would likely take the first differences of the observations and then estimate the parameters of the time series model. Taking the first differences would ensure stationarity of the data, as every good statistician knows :). Here is an example of an image from a [blogpost](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/08/auto-arima-time-series-modeling-python-r/). A shorthand ARIMA model is below with the AR and MA coefficients.

$$
y_t = \alpha + \beta_1 y_{t-1} + \cdots + \gamma_1 \epsilon_{t-1} + \cdots + \epsilon_t
$$

[image]

However, in the applied math world we often fit parameters to a model based upon data. So I have a model and I want estimate the parameters of the differential equation. I would then define the loss function as the difference between the data and the solution of the ordinary differentiation given the parameter values. There are many ways to do this including shooting methods, collocation methods, etc. But I have never seen anyone think of stationarity when applying these ODE parameter fitting methods. The example below is taken from a [tutorial](https://turing.ml/dev/tutorials/10-bayesian-differential-equations/) for the Turing package in Julia. The simple ODE model below is vector values, but the fundamental equation is a function of the state $y$, time $t$, and a vector of parameters $\theta$.

$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y, t, \theta)
$$

[image]

Hence I was just wondering if there is a good explanation why ODE fitting methods don't really need to think about stationarity? Indeed, I am working on a discrete time series simulation with some difference equations, so I am right in the middle of this issue, haha.

I do have some basic intuition here. Interestingly enough, the ODE methods are essentially capturing the first differences, because the function $f(y, t, \theta)$, when discretized numerically, is the first difference scaled by the size of the timestep, or $\frac{dy}{dt} =  \frac{f(y_{t+1}) - f(y_{t})}{h}$. But I was not sure how this finite difference idea relates back to the fundamental idea of stationarity? That is the crucial link that is kinda eluding me. If anyone has some thoughts, please chime in.

Comment: It is not in general necessary to "make data stationary", nor does taking a difference guarantee that it is, "as every good statistician knows".

Comment: @ChrisHaug, yes I was a bit coy with that comment, but most/many times we can improve or resolve issues with non-stationary time-series using first differences. I could think of ways that differencing does not make a particular non-stationary time-series into a stationary one, but that is really not the point of the question. The question is really about 2 different approaches to fitting time-series curves, and why ODE folks use finite differences, but often don't engage issues of stationarity when estimating ODE parameters.

Comment: A lack of stationarity is not in general an *issue* that needs to be *resolved*. The only issue is when you have a statistical model that has properties that don't align with your data. In the case of fitting ODE's, if you have a statistical model at all (if you don't then there is no concept of stationarity), it will be something like assuming the difference between the observed $y_t$ and the solution to the ODE at $t$ is iid. Hence, it's the *errors* that you're assuming are stationary, it is not necessary for the *data* to be stationary.

Comment: Hmm, yes the stationarity issue is about the distribution of the errors and the fact that there are correlations between the errors which then affects the estimation of statistical model parameters. So the idea seems focused on the correlation between adjacent points in the dataset, or $x_i, x_j$. In the context of an ODE model, because these are in continuous time, it seems like the idea is to minimize the error between each datapoint and the model. We seem to assume that each datapoint is normally distributed around the ODE solution. ODE models are more flexible than statistical models.

Comment: In what sense are ODE models "more flexible" than statistical models? The continuous time aspect has no relation to any of this. There are continuous time statistical models. You can also have discrete time models where the data is not required to be stationary. It's difficult to answer this question because there seems to be a lot of confusion about a lot of different things here.